# Create random number between X and Y, that cannot be Z in Java: remove element from list

Tags: java, list, integer

I want to move character on a 2D board. The board has a finite width and height (e.g. six columns, six rows). Let's say a piece is on the board at 0,0. I want to let it randomly move in a direction. However, considering it's at 0,0 it can't move up or left, and so on. I thought the best way to deal with this would be to start with all the movement options open, and then remove the ones that are impossible.

Here's what I got so far. `xPosition` and `yPosition` are the original positions of the element (defined in the constructor).

```
public void move() {
        int[][] world = new int[6][6];
        int worldRows = world[0].length;
        int worldCols = world.length;

        Random randomInt = new Random();
        List<Integer> directionOptions = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);

        /*
         * 1 = move up      3 = move down
         * 2 = move right   4 = move left
         */

        // Entity is in left column
        if (this.xPosition == 0) {
            directionOptions.remove((Integer) 4);
        }
        // Entity is in right column
        if (this.xPosition == worldCols) {
            directionOptions.remove((Integer) 2);
        }
        // Entity is in top row
        if (this.yPosition == 0) {
            directionOptions.remove((Integer) 1);
        }
        // Entity is in bottom row
        if (this.yPosition == worldRows) {
            directionOptions.remove((Integer) 3);
        }

        int randomMove = directionOptions.get(randomInt.nextInt(directionOptions.size()));

        switch(randomMove) {
            // 1: Move up
            case 1: this.yPosition = this.yPosition - 1;
                break;
            // 2: Move right
            case 2: this.xPosition = this.xPosition + 1;
                break;
            // 3: Move down
            case 3: this.yPosition = this.yPosition + 1;
                break;
            // 4: Move left
            case 4: this.xPosition = this.xPosition - 1;
                break;
        }
    }
```

But I when calling move on an entity (e.g. `john.move()`) I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.remove(Unknown Source)
    at Entity.move(Entity.java:48) // directionOptions.remove((Integer) 4);
    at Game.main(Game.java:21) // john.move()
```

Which points to the contents of the first if-clause: `directionOptions.remove((Integer) 4);`. What am I doing wrong? Why can't I remove an Integer from my Integer list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change from

```
List<Integer> directionOptions = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

to

```
List<Integer> directionOptions = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4));
```

[`Arrays.asList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) gives you a `List` backed by an array and you can't add or remove from it .